# Magento 2 : Add discount label on product page (already in Category view)

Tags: product-images, custom-discount

Hi the Magento Community,

I would like to add a discount label on my pictures on my product pages : I already have one for each product on category page (see picture below) but not on product pages.

I took the code from the category, but I don't know where I should paste it and if it will work with fotorama.

**My question is : Is it possible and which file I need to edit ?**

[image: Category image with label]

**Here is the code (I use Porto Theme) :**

```
<?php
                        $product_label = "";
                        if($_product_label_config['sale_label']) {
                            $orgprice = $_product->getPrice();
                            $specialprice = $_product->getSpecialPrice();
                            $specialfromdate = $_product->getSpecialFromDate();
                            $specialtodate = $_product->getSpecialToDate();
                            $today = time();
                            if(!$specialprice)
                                $specialprice = $orgprice;
                            if($specialprice < $orgprice) {
                                if((is_null($specialfromdate) && is_null($specialtodate)) || ($today >= strtotime($specialfromdate) && is_null($specialtodate)) || ($today <= strtotime($specialtodate) && is_null($specialfromdate)) || ($today >= strtotime($specialfromdate) && $today <= strtotime($specialtodate))){
                                    if($_product_label_config['sale_label_percent']) {
                                        $save_percent = 100-round(($specialprice/$orgprice)*100);
                                        $product_label .= '<div class="product-label sale-label">'.'-'.$save_percent.'%'.'</div>';
                                    } else {
                                        $product_label .= '<div class="product-label sale-label">'.$_product_label_config['sale_label_text'].'</div>';
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if($_product_label_config['new_label']) {
                            $now = date("Y-m-d");
                            $newsFrom= substr($_product->getData('news_from_date'),0,10);
                            $newsTo=  substr($_product->getData('news_to_date'),0,10);

                            if ($newsTo != '' || $newsFrom != ''){
                                if (($newsTo != '' && $newsFrom != '' && $now>=$newsFrom && $now<=$newsTo) || ($newsTo == '' && $now >=$newsFrom) || ($newsFrom == '' && $now<=$newsTo)) {
                                    $product_label .= '<div class="product-label new-label">'.$_product_label_config['new_label_text'].'</div>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if($product_label)
                            echo '<div class="product-labels">'.$product_label.'</div>';
                    ?>
```

Comment: Porto theme provides such features, check their documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on a developer setting which will show you which template is loading each element on a page. Follow the steps on Magento's documentation for it:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/debug-theme.html#debug-theme-templ